# Mezzanine : use KeywordsField as categories

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I would like to use Mezzanine KeywordsField as a category provider for my Django website. The idea is that **superusers can set up new tags but staff members can't**, and staff members can use those tags (as if they were keywords) when they create or edit a new post.

So far, i didn't find any way to achieve this because every staff user can add a keyword without restriction. How can I **forbid staff members to add keywords**?

Thank you for reading this post !